# Java Cron Jobs Stop for one hour a day?

Tags: java, cron, crontrigger

I am developing java application and in this I wanted to run some method periodically. I have used java schedule to run that method periodically. This is my Cron Expression.

```
/* runs in twelth second by every 5 minutes*/   
public static String CRON_TIME = "12 0/5 * * * ?";
```

This works fine. Now I wanted to stop running this scheduler for one hour per day. How I can write Cron Expression to do it? Give me a idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to exclude between 01:00 and 02:00 then use:

```
"12 0/5 0,2-23 * * ?"
```